# Read .csv data in european format with Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, syntax

I am currently doing my first attempts with Apache Spark. 
I would like to read a .csv File with an SQLContext object, but Spark won't provide the correct results as the File is a european one (comma as decimal separator and semicolon used as value separator). 
Is there a way to tell Spark to follow a different .csv syntax?

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local[8]")
            .setAppName("Foo")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat")
            .option("header","true")
            .option("inferSchema","true")
            .load("data.csv")

df.show()
```

A row in the relating .csv looks like this:

```
04.10.2016;12:51:00;1,1;0,41;0,416
```

Spark interprets the entire row as a column. `df.show()` prints:

```
+--------------------------------+
|Col1;Col2,Col3;Col4;Col5        |
+--------------------------------+
|            04.10.2016;12:51:...|
+--------------------------------+
```

In previous attempts to get it working `df.show()` was even printing more row-content where it now says '...' but eventually cutting the row at the comma in the third col.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just read as Test and split by ; or set a custom delimiter to the CSV format as in `.option("delimiter",";")`

Comment: Does it read in the numbers with comma (`,`) as decimal separator properly?